# PHP sum array values (on condition) result is 0

Tags: php, arrays, sum

With

```
print_r($assets_total);
echo ' print_r($assets_total)<br>';
```

Get such array

```
Array ( [0] => 21.00 [1] => 29.00 [2] => -50.00 ) print_r($assets_total)
```

Then simply want to sum all values.

```
echo $assets_total_sum = array_sum($assets_total);
```

Result is 0

Where is error?

Tried one other way

```
if( $result['AccountType'] == 'Asset' ) {
$assets_total[] = $result['Amount'];
$assets_total_1 += $result['Amount'];
}
echo $assets_total_1. ' $assets_total_1<br>';
```

Again result is 0

Question is clear/closed. My negligence. Did not pay attention to values.

Comment: 21 + 29 + (-50) is 0. There's no error here.

Comment: oh, sorry, stupid me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think nothing is wrong here, your array already equals to zero

```
Array ( [0] => 21.00 [1] => 29.00 [2] => -50.00
```

21 + 29 + -50 = 0

Comment: Yes. Did not paid attention to values... my negligence